# OnElementPropertyChanged is not triggered in iOS custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

OnElementPropertyChanged is not triggered in iOS custom renderer.

I have created a class library. In my Customer Renderer class i have override a OnElementPropertyChanged and this should be called whenever the Property of my View gets changed.

**XamarinForms:**

```
public class CustomControl : View
{
    public int PageNumber
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PageNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PageNumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PageNumberProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<CustomControl, int>(p => p.PageNumber, 0, BindingMode.Default, null, null);


}
```

**CustomRenderer Class iOS:**

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomControl), typeof(CustomRenderer))]

 namespace XForms.iOS
{    
internal class CustomRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomControl, UIScrollView>
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you adding this CustomControl to your XAML ? using local namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check that it is really using the custom renderer by putting a breakpoint into it.

Next make sure that you change proper (`PageNumber`) *after* creation of the UI element. During the creation process, property change notifications will not be sent. A similar case is described in the Xamarin [forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26060/why-is-onelementpropertychanged-not-called-on-viewrenderer).